# Get type of object deserialized by custom deserializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a custom `@JacksonDeserializer` for an abstract super-class:

```
@JacksonDeserializer
public abstract class MyObject {

    private String id;
    ...
}

public class MyObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arctxtg1)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {


        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String id = node.get("id").asText();
        System.out.println("ID = "+id);

        //Here I need to determine which type of MyObject
        //currently needs to be deserialized.


    }

}
```

My system knows 8 sub-classes of this class, of which some but not all of them have unique attributes.

Now I'm getting a JSON object from the client, which includes a `ArrayList<myObject>` that I have to deserialize on the server and map to existing objects to update them.

The problem is that for all sub-classes the same `@JacksonDeserializer` gets called and I can't figure out if/how I can access the type of class to be deserialized in the `@override deserialize()` method.
The problem is that I cannot instantiate the abstract super-class obviously and i can't instantiate any of the sub-classes either since I can't determine to which the currently deserialized object belongs to.

So the question is: Is there any way I can get the information of which sub-class needs to be instantiated from the deserializer?

What makes me think that this should be possible:
When I instantiate one of the subclasses at random (e.g. MyObject1 i get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
com.myCompany.myPackage.MyObject1 cannot be cast to 
com.myCompany.myPackage.MyObject2
```

Where MyObject2 is the information I actually need. This made me think that the Deserializer class has to have this information somewhere.

Comment: Don't you have any attribute that you can use as a guideline to find the proper Java class to deserialize your JSON?

Comment: Sadly not, i can accuratelly find 3 out of 8 subclasses but I have no information whatsoever for the other 5.

Comment: If you don't have any attribute or value that can be used to pick the right Java class, well, I think the news won't be good then...

Comment: I thought about just cutting the right substring from the `JsonMappingException` which could work with a lot of String manipulation. I was just wondering if there is a nicer way to extract this information, since it's cleary stored somewhere in the `MyObjectDeserializer`.

Answer (score 0):

As Cassio said, if you don't have any attribute that can help you to determine which type your JSON object is, you will not be able to deserialize it using the correct ObjectMapper.

Maybe your JSON should contain this kind of information.